# Can't perform PUT command in PostMan

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, postman

I am new in the world of Spring Boot and MongoDB so this could be a stupid question.

I created a Spring Boot project linked to a MondoDB database. In the Controller I've defined these methods: get, getAll, add, update and delete.

Everything works fine while I test my app on PostMan, except for the update method. Indeed in PostMan, using the PUT command, I get this error:

"status": 405,
"error": "Method Not Allowed"

Looking for a solution, I found these lines in PostMan:
[PUT non allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK8My.jpg)

where the value of "Allow"only contains "GET, DELETE" and not PUT.

Maybe this fact is linked to my error? How can I fix it?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english and lack of knowledge of SpringBoot!

EDIT 1: Controller code:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity <Cliente> updateCliente(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id, @RequestBody Cliente cliente){
    Optional<Cliente> c = clienteRepo.findById(id);
    
    Cliente _c = new Cliente();
    if(c.isPresent()) {
        _c = c.get();
        _c.setId(cliente.getId());
        _c.setNome(cliente.getNome());
    }
    final Cliente updatedCliente = clienteRepo.save(_c);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedCliente);
}
```

EDIT 2: PostMan request:
[PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkI7b.jpg)

Comment: This might help https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-method-not-supported-405

Comment: can you share the controller code? It maybe missing PUT method! Or you maybe calling wrong method by mistake from Postman!

Comment: Can you show how you're making the PUT request on Postman?

Comment: Please paste code, not links to images with code.
You can use Markdown to format code correctly, for example: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code

Answer (score 1):

You can check the mapped api in the log by adding the following config in the application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation=TRACE
```

For example:
I have a controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/client")
public class HomeRestController {

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public void put(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id, @RequestBody TestingModel model) {
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(model.getName());
    }
}
```

When starting the application you can see the mapped API in the console log as below:

```
    2020-07-14 09:36:49.287 TRACE 13224 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 
    c.e.e.c.HomeController:
    { /index}: home()
2020-07-14 09:36:49.288 TRACE 13224 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 
    c.e.e.c.HomeRestController:
    {PUT /client/{id}}: put(String,TestingModel)
2020-07-14 09:36:49.293 TRACE 13224 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 
    o.s.b.a.w.s.e.BasicErrorController:
    { /error}: error(HttpServletRequest)
    { /error, produces [text/html]}: errorHtml(HttpServletRequest,HttpServletResponse)
```